# How to extract strings occurring after a certain character in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, string

If, I have a string:

```
'#name#user#user2#laugh#cry'
```

I would like to print,

```
name
user
user2
laugh
cry
```

All the strings are different and have a different number of `'#'`.

I have tried using Regex but it's not working. What logic has to be applied for this query?

Comment: Some things are better done in application code than in SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to say is that storing delimited list of values in text columns is, in many ways, not a good database design. You should basically rework your database structure, or prepare for a potential world of pain.

A quick and dirty solution is to use a numbers table, or an inline suquery, and to cross join it with the table ; `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` (available in MySQL 8.0), lets you select a given occurence of a particular pattern.

Here is a query that will extract up to 10 values from the column:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.val, '[^#]+', 1, numbers.n) name
FROM
    mytable t
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT 1 n UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 
        UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 
        UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10
) numbers
    ON REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.val, '[^#]+', 1, numbers.n) IS NOT NULL
```

Regexp `[^#]+` means: as many consecutive characters as possible other than `#`.

---

Ths **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fM6UjyMYArWiTPPsRAaWD8/0)**, when given input string `'#name#user#user2#laugh#cry'`, returns:

```
| name  |
| ----- |
| name  |
| user  |
| user2 |
| laugh |
| cry   |
```